# Android best method to send files from client to server when network is not stable

Tags: java, android

I'm using **HttpURLConnection** to send files to the server from my android application. It's working fine when network is stable.

Whenever the network is not stable and I'm sending the files again and again to the server some data is missing.

Can any one tell me whether the **Socket** implementation will solve this issue? or any other solution will help me in handling this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big are the data?

Comment: It's nearly 30 MB xml file.

Comment: Blimey! OK, my ideas of an initial ping to detect network won't be adequate (which works 99.9% of the time for me with small JSON files). If I get a ping success, chances are the network will stay up long enough for 2-3kb data transfer. Can you break the data down in any way?

Comment: ok, you mean by splitting up the data and sending to the server as chunk by chunk?

Comment: Yes, that's all I can think of, but it's still a lot of data to transfer. Sorry not to be more helpful. Good luck.

Comment: @ iaindownie: thanks for your reply. Let me wait for any other solutions. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should check network failure test cases.When network is failure while data transfering ,
you should maintain the list of items which is not sent.When network is connected,then try to send  remaining items.